# Send a function from one page and running it on another

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have access to both pages on my localhost. The page I want to send the function to is in an frame on the page I want to send it from. Would postmessage work and setting up an event listener in the receiver/iframe page? The function is:

```
 ipa.searchByString(query);
```

Listener syntax:

```
ipa.addListener('query', myAppEventHandler);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you *could* send a function as a string from one page to another, but that won't work well if the function dependa on other functions variables. And generally I don't think you want that here. Instead propagate the handler to the messaging channel:

```
 ipa.addListener('query', function proxy(data) {
   iframe.postMessage({ name: "ipa", data });
 });
```

Then receice it on the other page:

```
 window.onmessage = e => {
   const { name, data } = e.data;
   if(name === "ipa") myAppEventHandler(data);
};
```